# Let $m(x)= (1+|x|^2)^{s/2}.$ Can we find constant and $f$ so $m(x+y) \leq C f(x) m(y) $

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

Define $m(x)= (1+|x|^2)^{s/2}, \ x \in \mathbb R^d, s\in \mathbb R.$

Can we expect to find function $f$ on $\mathbb R^d$ so that
$$m(x_1+x_2) \leq C f(x_1) m(x_2) $$ for all $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb R^d.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\langle x \rangle=(1+\vert x \vert^2)^{1/2}$ (often called Japanese bracket) and $w\in \mathbb{R}$, then a simple application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality yields 
$$
\langle x+y\rangle^w \le 2^{\vert w \vert /2 }\langle x\rangle^w\langle y\rangle^{\vert w\vert},\quad x,y\in\mathbb{R}^d.
$$
Try to prove it yourself, or otherwise look up Lemma 4.3 in Peter Hintz' (excellent) [lecture notes](https://math.mit.edu/~phintz/18.157-S19/index.html) on microlocal analysis.

Comment: Thanks. But how does this help to solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I submitted prematurely.

Comment: The question contains a power two that your expressions don't contain